# C/C++ standard library wrapper with exceptions

Tags: c++, c, exception, wrapper

I'm looking for classes like "File, Socket, String" wrapping the C (or C++) standard library functions and throwing exceptions in case of errors.

Comment: There aren't any C standard library functions for socket programming. and files and strings are covered by the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: @Neil is right that they aren't part of the C standard.  However, there are POSIX standard functions for socket programming, and the `boost::asio` library provides wrappers for them.

Comment: Ok, but i was looking for a different kind of "covering" (using classes and exceptions).

Comment: @user791229: Why do you want to use wrapper classes using C standard library functions? Why not just use the ones provided by the C++ standard library?

Comment: i'd like make use of the old C logic in C++, but take advantage of OOP.

Comment: @user That isn't possible. Or sensible.

Comment: It's unfortunate (IMHO) that the Standard C++ Library classes generally don't throw exceptions when errors occur, but you should probably use them anyway.

Comment: i think it is possible, for istance wxWidgets has socket and file classes, but they do not thrown exceptions (http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxsocketbase.html#wxsocketbase) (http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxfile.html#wxfile) (http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_exceptions.html) The reason is that exceptions were added in C++ after C++SL and wxwidgets development.

Comment: @user No, they were not.

Comment: this one has exceptions too: (http://sourceforge.net/projects/fedlibrary/)

Comment: another one (http://www.hyperrealm.com/main.php?s=commoncpp)

Comment: this one probably is the most complete and popular, but uses the new stream-oriented API: (http://pocoproject.org)

Comment: i've found gtkmm also has a stream-oriented wrapper for files (http://www.gtkmm.org/en/documentation.html). Other non-stream oriented alternatives are welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the question wasn't clear,
btw i've found this library is exactly what i was looking for:
[commonc++](http://www.hyperrealm.com/main.php?s=commoncpp).

Edit: [Better alternative still maintained](http://pocoproject.org/).